# How to avoid/fix "Auth0Lock is not defined" exception

Tags: auth0, http-token-authentication, angular2-jwt

I am trying to use the Auth0 for social login but I keep getting an exception of an undefined reference.

#### This is the authentication service

```
import { Injectable }      from '@angular/core';
import { tokenNotExpired } from 'angular2-jwt';

// Avoid name not found warnings
declare var Auth0Lock: any;

@Injectable()
export class AuthService {
// Configure Auth0

lock = new Auth0Lock('I have set the ID correctly here', 'and the domain as well', {});

constructor() {
// Add callback for lock `authenticated` event
  this.lock.on("authenticated", (authResult) => {
  localStorage.setItem('id_token', authResult.idToken);
  });
}

public login() {
// Call the show method to display the widget.
  this.lock.show();
};

public authenticated() {
  // Check if there's an unexpired JWT
  // This searches for an item in localStorage with key == 'id_token'
  return tokenNotExpired();
};

public logout() {
   // Remove token from localStorage
    localStorage.removeItem('id_token');
  };
}
```

I injected the services and configured providers. Everything is wired correctly, but it just won't find `Auth0Lock` even though defined.
Each time it reaches `lock = new Auth0Lock('ID', 'DOMAIN', {});` it bombs out.

Comment: It's normal for the person that asks the question to end up solving it, so it's totally fine for you to add your own solution as an answer and accepting it. This improves visibility of the solution to people searching for similar issues and also clearly indicates that the question is answered.

Comment: Alright, thanks, let me do that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I replaced `declare var Auth0Lock: any;` with `const Auth0Lock = require('auth0-lock').default;` and that fixed the problem.

Comment: require isn't working for me - I get "auth.service.ts (8,17): Cannot find name 'require'.
webpack: Failed to compile."

Answer (score 3):

The accepted answer is good. I did get a **Cannot find name 'require'** error.
Rather than using 'declare const require', I imported like so:

`import Auth0Lock from 'auth0-lock';`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Aut0 in HTML file and all your code are wrapped in .html file, then you should go for this answer:

```
<script src="https://cdn.auth0.com/js/lock/11.34.2/lock.min.js"></script>
```

It will definitely help you.

Answer (score -2):

I needed to add to `index.html`:

`<script src="https://cdn.auth0.com/js/lock/10.8/lock.min.js"></script>`

via https://github.com/auth0/lock/issues/588